# Is there a way to disable the mmu for a specific block memory?

Tags: c, linux

If we can access some block memory without mmu, while accessing other memory with mmu, a good performance gain can be achieved. I have read the intelx86_64 manual, and only to find that mission seems impossible...Or perhaps can we disble the mmu to work when accessing the specifice memory?

Can someone tell the answer to me ? Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think disabling the MMU will give you a performance gain?

Comment: Please believe me: you are asking for unending trouble when you fool around with the MMU.

Comment: @qbert220: TLB misses are quite costly. That said, a better way would be to use large page support than mucking with disabling paging.

Comment: Are you planning on doing this without an operating system on the machine, or with?

Comment: @zvrba: You are right, I have thought about this way, using large pages to reference those memory. But no mmu is prefered, in case that we can do it:).

Comment: -1 for seeking out horrible hacks for premature optimization. I'm quite sure you have much bigger sources of performance problems than TLB misses.

Comment: @R. yes, but there is a place for esoterica, or maybe even academia too. This horrible hack could become someones bachelors' exam. :-)

Comment: @ACK: And Linux will forever be enlarged with useless code (and thus complexity) that's only of interest for esoteric academic purposes, and which eventually leads to vulnerabilities on real-world systems all over the place. Thanks for reminding me why I love Linux.....

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, you cannot.

Long answer: you can write a kernel module that switches the CPU to 32-bit mode (if in 64-bit mode) and disables paging, while remaining in protected mode.  During that time, you would be able to run only pure computations, i.e., no input/output (including networking) would be possible. (Presuming that you want to be able to restore the OS kernel and other running applications to their original state, which is essentially a must if you want to be able to save the results of your computations.)

Comment: Nice answer. And no TLB misses, thus no penalties?

Comment: It might actually even be simpler! On a multicore system, you could 1) make the kernel allocate contiguous physical memory (possibly through compaction), 2) "steal" one core from the OS (shouldn't be too hard if the OS supports hotplugging) and disable paging on it, 3) start running the code on that core.

Comment: Haha, I like these odd use cases. Probably no one does these things, but it's nice to know it's probably possible. You could get really, really good real-time performance on that core if you stayed within its L1 cache.

Comment: Actually, I ran into a research article from Intel or MS (don't recall exactly), where they actually did exactly that for some performance tests. It was running on Windows NT.

Comment: @Prof.Falken: If you disable paging, then do your thing, then enable paging again afterwards; then you've completely trashed all TLBs and the performance gain you may or may not get (while paging is off) will probably be nothing compared to the performance nightmare of "everything is a TLB miss" immediately after turning paging back on.

Comment: @Brendan, was this directed at me?

Comment: @Prof.Falken: Yes - in response to "Nice answer. And no TLB misses, thus no penalties?". There's no TLB misses when paging is off, but as soon as you turn it back on (e.g. so the kernel can handle an IRQ and the system doesn't completely lock up) there's lots of TLB misses

Comment: Ah. I can see how that could happen. @Brendan.